# Which site is better for questions about protracted visitor visas?

Tags: discussion

In some countries it's possible to extend visitor visas to much longer than a tourist would usually stay; you could be on such a visa paying rent, getting dental cleanings, etc., though you're not taking local work.  I know someone even with kids in school under such visas.

Questions about such extensions and the like seem to lie somewhere between Travel.SE and Expatriates.SE.

I suspect these might be considered on-topic at either site, but I am more so wondering at which site such questions would be more likely to attract better answers.

On one hand, Travel has on the order of 10x more answers than Expatriates.  In fact, for some countries there are only a few questions here in total, but hundreds on Travel.

OTOH, on Travel, much of the Q/A, though not all, pertains to more touristic concerns, so "more Q/A" doesn't necessarily translate to "more likely to answer on intermediate topics."

Which community is better for these sorts of questions?

Answer (score 1):

These questions would likely be on-topic here - you don't need to work somewhere to be an expatriate, and usually after 3-6 months of staying somewhere (which is the usual limit of most tourist visas) you will have different problems than someone who only spends a couple weeks in the country.

Whether these questions are on-topic on Travel.SE, I have no idea, but they might not be - I remember a couple questions that have been migrated from there over here that fall into the category you seek. You can definitely ask this question over there on the Meta as well. If they do allow - I would say because of the bigger community you will find more answers over there. A lot of the people who frequent this site also have an account on Travel as well, so it's likely you'll still receive answers from members who have more experience with long(er)-term living.